# Make Eclipse Kepler into ONLY an XML editor

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, plugins

So I want to get rid of plugins that are not needed to display and edit an XML file on Eclipse. And eventually I want to create a plugin that reads the xml file and looks for errors and displays them to the user. Much like how Word will give a underline a word in red if it is spelled incorrectly.

Any one have an idea of which plugins I should delete and which ones I shouldn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend deleting plugins from the file system.

To achieve what you are looking for, follow these steps:

1. download the Eclipse Standard Edition
2. Open a new workspace
3. Go to 'Window' --> 'Preferences' --> 'General' --> 'Capabilities'
4. click on 'Disable All' button then 'OK' button
5. Restart the workspace

XML syntax validation is out of the box and no need to develop a special plugin for it. 
And even spelling validation is included.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on how to disable the capabilities, however I have one more question? 1) Which XML editor do you suggest I download from the Eclipse software page. 2) Also I wanted to make a special plug in that checks my XML file for errors in data (the idea being that Im taking a configuration file full of data, converting it to XML, and allowing the user to edit the data displayed. I was considering making a plugin to check that what they input/edit is valid)

Comment: If you'll just disable the capabilities, then I think Eclipse Standard is good.
If you need to just validate on the data entered that they are valid, like validating an email tag is actually a valid email, or amount tag is actually an amount, you can achieve this by creating a XML schema (which contains all sort of validations you like) and these XML files will be validated automatically (structure, data types, extra validations you added to your schema..etc)

If you will let your users enter a data like as in using a form, you may want to check EMF and EMF forms